# Can not import mysql.connect

Tags: python, mysql, anaconda

I cannot import mysql.connector module.

My project interpreter is anaconda 3.7.

Error message is ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql.connector'; 'mysql' is not a package.

I've tried these, but don't work for me.

1. pip install mysql-connector-python
2. pip install mysql-connector-python-rf
3. conda install -c anaconda mysql-connector-python

I've already checked the same questions, but I couldn't solve this.
Is there anyone who solve this issue?

```
/Users/mymac/anaconda3/bin/python /Users/mymac/PycharmProjects/test_python/mysql.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../mysql.py", line 1, in [module]
import mysql.connector
  File "../mysql.py", line 1, in [module]
   import mysql.connector
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql.connector'; 'mysql' is not a package
```

Comment: What was your import command?

Comment: import mysql.connector

Comment: If you're using anaconda, the pip commands are irrelevant. Are you sure you're starting the correct interpreter? Are you using virtual environments?

Comment: I am not using virtualenv. but conda install command does not work too.

Comment: What is the name of the file where you want to import the connector with that `import mysql.connector` statement? Please add the full traceback, i.e. the complete error message to your question.

Comment: OK. I uploaded it

Comment: You named your script `mysql.py`. That shadows the `mysql` package. Python now tries to import the module `connector` from *your script*. But, your script is not a package, hence no module can be imported from it, hence no module found. Rename your script and make sure you don't use the names of standard library or 3rd party packages and modules for your scripts.

Answer (score -1):

i solved this issue by running `pip install pymysql` command in cmd then write python code like this..

```
import pymysql
print("connecting to mysql server")
conn=pymysql.connect (host ="localhost", user="userName" , passwd="abc",db="database_name")
cursore=conn.cursor()  
print("connected completly")
```

Comment: That installs and uses a completely different package. In what way does it solve the problem while attempting to import the `connector` module of the `mysql` package?